# "Unexpected" TypeError: unexpected keyword

Tags: python, python-2.7, typeerror, keyword-argument

I have written this function in a package of mine.

```
def partitionIntoDays(ls, number, lookupKey=None):
    ''' Partitions the location measurements into days.
    @ls: The list of measurements you want to partition
    @return: A dictionary in the format {'Number of partition':
    'List of measurements'}'''
    if len(ls) == 0:
        return {0: []}
    firstMidnight = TimeAux.localTimeToEpoch(Delorean(TimeAux.epochToLocalTime(ls[0].time, TIMEZONE)).midnight())
    return splitByTimedelta(ls, delta=number*24*3600, lowerBound=firstMidnight, lookupKey=lookupKey)
```

But whenever I try to call the function from a script I get the following error:

```
TypeError: partitionIntoDays() got an unexpected keyword argument 'lookupKey'
```

However if I import the function somewhere manually, I can check that the function has the argument. For example, I can even do this while I am debugging the above error in pdb.

```
import geogps.Partition as pt
pt.partitionIntoDays.func_code.co_varnames
>>>>('ls', 'number', 'lookupKey', 'firstMidnight')
```

Also the above code works fine in Python 3.4. 
I am in short completely flabbergasted.

Comment: does `splitByTimedelta` take an argument called `lookupKey`?

Comment: How are u calling partitionIntoDays function in your script?

Comment: `co_varnames` is a list of variablenames used *in the function body*. More important is `co_argcount` which tells you how many of those names are arguments.

Comment: Yes, `splitByTimedelta` takes an argument called `lookupKey`.

Comment: And how are you importing and calling the function?

Comment: `pt.partitionIntoDays.func_code.co_argcount` returns 3. As I would expect it to be.

Comment: This is how I am calling the function
`days = Partition.partitionIntoDays(locations, 1, lookupKey=lookupKey)` where this is how I define lookupKey: `lookupKey=lambda x:x.time`

Comment: Are you sure you import the same module from your script and from the shell ? You may have another version in the python path for your script (beware of stall .pyc files !). Or could it be you have another eponym function shadowing the one you want to call ? (beware of "star imports" - `from somewhere import *` - they can easily break your code).

Comment: And I am importing it this way: `from geogps import Partition`

Comment: Side note, the first `return` should be indented.

Comment: I just created a new virtual environment to make sure that there is no old pyc file lurking around somewhere. I still get the same error...

Comment: It's not wrapped in a decorator is it?

Comment: No decorators. I am just searching for all possible pyc files, maybe I missed one somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out: While there were no lingering pyc files, my package structure was messed up and I had an extraneous file in a nested folder.
Thanks @bruno-desthuilliers for pointing me the right way.